# Como actualizar commit de repositorio remoto que fue editado en repositorio local

Tags: git, git-commit

Estaba creando un repositorio con unas pruebas y luego de subirlo a la cuenta remota, me di cuenta que mi commit tenía un error, pude editarlo utilizando

```
git commit --amend
```

Mi consulta es, cómo podría actualizar el repositorio remoto ya que este sigue con el error con que lo subí.
Para actualizar los cambios del repositorio remoto normalmente uso

```
git push origin master
```

Pero en este caso pensé que actualizaría el commit remoto pero me tiró un error.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si usas `--amend`   es porque sobreescribiste la historia, entonces

puedes forzar la subida con

```
git push -f
```

Comment: lo mandé asi: "git push -f origin master"  sirvió. Gracias